# UI Bug in Job Recommendation section (text overlap)?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I see this UI bug for the last few days in Job recommendation section, it's Safari browser.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug with the person providing the job description... /s <-- that means "end sarcasm" :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey ))) haha, it's the first time I see such a long job title

Comment: Adding `word-wrap` in the CSS should fix this right?